# xpath like query for protobuf messages

Tags: xpath, protocol-buffers, jsonpath

I am looking for a xpath like query language for protobuf messages. For example, for the Person message shown below [ borrowed from the Developer guide ]

```
message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }

  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
  }

  repeated PhoneNumber phone = 4;
}
```

I would like to have methods like

```
XPBQuery.get(person, "$.id") ==> returns the id
XPBQuery.get(person, "$.name") ==> returns the name
XPBQuery.get(person, "$.phone.number[0]") ==> returns the first phone number
```

One way is to convert the proto to Json and use a JsonPath/JsPath API's. But it may be expensive to convert to Json everytime especially for large Proto objects.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Irfan

Comment: I don't know if this exists already, but if not you can implement this in terms of the Protobuf descriptor and reflection interfaces (not to be confused with Java reflection -- Protobuf reflection is provided by the Protobuf library). See `com.google.protobuf.Message` in Java or `google::protobuf::Reflection` in C++.

Comment: @Irfan - Wanted to check if you figured out a way to achieve this? I want to take out JSON.NET (that supports JSONPath) and use ProtoBuf, but lack of querying capability stops me.

Comment: If you convert your message to java bean then you may use [JXPath](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/users-guide.html)

Answer (score 1):

Support for that is coming in protobuf v3: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/4644f99d1af4250dec95339be6a13e149787ab33/src/google/protobuf/field_mask.proto

Answer (score 0):

While looking for a solution to a similar problem I discovered:

- [PbQuery](https://github.com/pkuzco/pbquery) (python)
- [protobuf-utils](https://github.com/temk/protobuf-utils) (java)
- [protobuf-el](https://github.com/protobufel/protobuf-el) (java)

(I did not use those libraries as my target language is C++, but hope this might help someone else)

Good luck!